# Remove ion item divider

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, divider

How I can remove `<ion-item>` divider? I have the following code to show 4 items in a row:

```
<ion-row ion-list>
    <ion-col width-25 *ngFor="let player of players">
              <ion-item color="dark">
                  <ion-avatar item-left>
                      <img [src]="photo" class="img img-circle"/>
                  </ion-avatar>
                  {{user.name}}
              </ion-item>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
```

and the output shows 4 images in a row, as excepted, but each image has a white divider below it. I don't want any divider.

I tried to set `style="border:none"` but it didn't do it.

Comment: show the image/screenshot.. Hard to understand... May be `ion-col, ion-row`  has some css which is showing the border.

Comment: Usually in grid systems there is padding in place to create "air" between the blocks. I think style="padding: 0" on your ion-col element should do the trick.

But I think maybe you should rethink the use of ion-row and ion-cols here as it seems a little too complex for your needs.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**This is for ionic 2 and 3. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433918/4826457) for higher versions of ionic**

use `no-lines`

```
<ion-row ion-list>
    <ion-col width-25 *ngFor="let player of players">
         <ion-item no-lines color="dark"><!-- here -->
              <ion-avatar item-left>
                  <img [src]="photo" class="img img-circle"/>
              </ion-avatar>
              {{user.name}}
         </ion-item>
     </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Thanks @jegadeesh, adding `<IonItem lines="none">` solved my problem in Ionic5!! Cheers!

Comment: @Bebbolin thanks, this worked with me :) lines="none"

Answer (score 68):

For whatever reason, this didn't work for me.
But having `lines="none"` worked great.

**For ionic v4**

`<ion-item lines="none">...</ion-item>`

Pulled from ionic docs. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list

Comment: This is for ionic v4 onwards.

Comment: Thanks Ionic for changing everything once again.

Comment: This works in angular 8, the marked solution does not

Comment: thanks for answer,it worked very well. That is a simple command that make me not need to spend hours searching a way to remove by force this little annoying line. Thank you very much haha

Answer (score 9):

For ionic v4, you should use the lines property:

```
<ion-row ion-list>
    <ion-col width-25 *ngFor="let player of players">
         <ion-item lines="none" color="dark">
              <ion-avatar item-left>
                  <img [src]="photo" class="img img-circle"/>
              </ion-avatar>
              {{user.name}}
         </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 9):

Apply this for Ionic V4. Really it will work.. Happy coding

```
<ion-item lines="none">
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to disable the lines / borders globally on all of your `<ion-item>`'s, just add the following code to your `src/global.scss` (default when generating a Ionic v4 App with Angular) of your application.

```
ion-item {

    --border-width: 0;
    --inner-border-width: 0;
}
```

The attribute `lines="none"` on a `<ion-item>` does nothing other.

Hope it helps someone.

Cheers
Unkn0wn0x

Comment: Thx. I was looking for a global solution.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with no-line but it didn't work in ionic 4

Only this work for me in ionic 4 :

```
<ion-item lines="none"> </ion-item>

<ion-list>
 <ion-item lines="none" button detail *ngFor="let note of notesService.notes">
      <ion-label>{{ note.title }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on ionic 4, and lines="none" somethimes don't work.
So I use this line.

```
ion-list:not(.list-lines-none) ion-item::before{
    border-width: 0 !important;
}
```

And this is my ionItem example. (It has hidden error property also)

```
<IonItem lines="none" detail={false}>
    <IonIcon
        className="w-40 h-40 float-left"
        src="/assets/icon/store-black.svg"
    />
    <IonLabel className="flex flex-col ml-10">
        <h5 className="text-base font-bold m-0 ">Lorem ipsum </h5>
        <span className="text-sm leading-tight">Kratki opis</span>
    </IonLabel>
    <IonIcon
        className=" absolute top-50 right-30 w-15 h-15"
        src="/assets/icon/arrow-right.svg"
    />
</IonItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

use (lines="none") in your ion-item

Answer (score 0):

Still `lines="none"` works in Ionic v7:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list style="text-align:center">
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label>
        <h6>Your text</h6>
        <ion-badge class="status-badge">
          <span>Your text</span>
        </ion-badge>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```