# How to remove bottom line from the ionic 2 components

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm using ionic 2.
I need to remove the bottom white line from the input field.
This is my addVehicle.html page,

```
<form [formGroup]="addCustomerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addCustomerForm)">
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Owner Name" class="ion_input" formControlName="vehicle_cust_name" name="vehicle_cust_name"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="person-add" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Vehical No" formControlName="vehicle_no" name="vehicle_no"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="car" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Tel No 1" formControlName="vehicle_cust_tel1" name="vehicle_cust_tel1"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="call" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Tel No 2" formControlName="vehicle_cust_tel2" name="vehicle_cust_tel2"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="call" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Address" formControlName="vehicle_cust_address" name="vehicle_cust_address"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="navigate" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Engine No" formControlName="vehicle_engine_no" name="vehicle_engine_no"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="construct" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-input type="text" class="ion_input" placeholder="Chassis No" formControlName="vehicle_chassis_no" name="vehicle_chassis_no"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="build" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-select class="ion_input" placeholder="Brand ID" formControlName="vehicle_vehicle_brand_id" [(ngModel)]="vehicle_vehicle_brand_id"
    multiple="false">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let brandId of brandIds.brand" [value]="brandId.brand_id">{{brandId.brand_name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  <ion-icon name="code" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="ion-card">
  <ion-select class="ion_input" placeholder="Type" formControlName="vehicle_vehicle_models_id" [(ngModel)]="vehicle_vehicle_models_id"
    multiple="false" (ionChange)="modelChanged(vehicle_vehicle_models_id)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let loadModel of loadModels.types" [value]="loadModel.models_id">{{loadModel.models_name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  <ion-icon name="code-working" class="ion_icon" item-left small></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button color="primary_btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!addCustomerForm.valid" block>
    Add Vehicle
    </button>
<button ion-button color="secondary_btn" type="button" (click)="cancleClick()" block>
    Cancel
    </button>
```

I used

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color:false;
```

And this is my .css

```
.ion-card{
background-color: #101218;
border: 1px solid #4A4A4A;
margin:20px auto;
border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.ion_input{
color:#f4f4f4;
opacity: 0.6;
}
.ion_icon{
color:#f4f4f4;
opacity: 0.6;
font-size: 5px;
}
.home_back{
 background-color: #15161D;
}
.item-inner, ion-item {
 border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```

for remove that white line which the image shows you.But I can't remove it.Is there a suggestion to overcome this issue guys

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376147/remove-ion-item-divider what you are asking?

Comment: when I'm using "no-lines" the border will also disappear.Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like there isn't a way to remove that by using Ionic Sass properties. That being said, we can remove it by just using some css style rules:

```
.item-md.item-block .item-inner,
.item-md.item-input.input-has-focus .item-inner,
.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner,
.item-md.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner,
.list-md .item-input.input-has-focus:last-child,
.list-md .item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus):last-child,
.list-md .item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.list-md .item-input.input-has-focus:last-child .item-inner,
.list-md .item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus):last-child .item-inner,
.list-md .item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):last-child .item-inner {
    box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Comment: .item-inner {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}   //using this,it removed both white line and the bottom border.I only need to remove the white line.not the border!Do you have a suggestion!

Comment: Hmm, could you please add to the question, the custom css that's being applied to each item?

Comment: Added it.Please check

Comment: I've updated the answer, please take a look at it when you have time :) This is the result: [Gyazo gif](https://i.gyazo.com/1e46a479932f8734c8a89cee711e5f8c.gif)

Comment: Glad to hear that @Vasanth :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to do the same for ios. This works only in android

Comment: @TapasMukherjee have you already tried by replacing the `.item-md` of each style by `.item-ios`?

Comment: It's working. Thanks. Is there a way it can be declared it in the scss variable file so that it reflects in every page.

Comment: Yes, if you declare those style rules in the `app.scss` file, they should be applied to every page

Comment: @sebaferreras, if we give "no-lines"property to ion-item, it will also remove that line. Right?

Comment: You need to add  !important to the properties.

Comment: @pasx that shouldn't be necessary since the rules are very specific. Could you please add some more information about why is the `!important` needed? (Feel free to edit the question if you want)

Comment: @sebaferreras I added the rules to my page scss first, then app.scss and in the list of rules, mines appear below the original rules so I needed to make them important for them to be applied.

Answer (score 20):

Just include `no-lines` in `ion-item`. Just like below

`<ion-item no-lines></ion-item>`

Comment: The best solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can now just add lines="none".

Example:

```
<ion-item class="ion-card" lines="none">
```

From:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

Answer (score 1):

just include your `<ion-item></ion-item>` elements within a `<ion-list inset></ion-list>`. Make sure you include `inset` property to your ion-list.

Answer (score 0):

On *ionic 3* this solution is working fine

```
 .item-inner {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class in ion-input and applying "text-decoration: none" style in that class worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You can just target the class `ion_input` with a wrapped `.md,.ios,.wp` like so

```
.md,.ios,.wp{
     .ion_input{
         border-bottom: none;
         box-shadow: none;
     }
}
```

Wrapping with those target classes overwrites any ionic base styles.