# How to remove separating line in Ionic 3 but keeping the ability to show borders?

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I know that I can remove the separating line in Ionic list by adding `no-lines` to the html ion-item, as already answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376147/remove-ion-item-divider).

My problem is that this removes the ability to have any of the borders (top, bottom, left, right). And in my particular problem, I need a top border of 2px above the ion-item.

Does anyone know any alternative way to remove the separating line that doesn't mess with the borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

Remove existing borders

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item no-lines>item 1</ion-item>
    <ion-item no-lines>item 2</ion-item>
    <ion-item no-lines>item 3</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Add border-top

```
ion-item { 
    border-top: 2px solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying something like that but it seems that "!important" saves the day! :)